# Install Go 1.8 with yum

Tags: linux, yum, amazon-ec2

I just set up an AWS AMI instance. I'm trying to install Go 1.8. When I ran `sudo yum install golang` it installed version 1.6.3. How can I make it install version 1.8?

```
[ec2-user@ip-123 ~]$ yum --showduplicates list golang | expand
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Available Packages
golang.x86_64                   1.5.3-1.22.amzn1                    amzn-main   
golang.x86_64                   1.6.3-2.57.amzn1                    amzn-updates
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any YUM repository that had dedicated packages in the version Go 1.8

Options that you would have in this case and that work, are compile via source code, as in these Howtos:

https://tecadmin.net/install-go-lang-on-centos/
https://tecadmin.net/install-go-on-centos/